# How to fix issue with celery workers writing payloads to the same file but output is often malformed

Tags: celery, django-celery

A legacy django & celery based service has been writing payloads in a newline to a file using celery workers. But I noticed a lot of malformed payloads ... A payload would start in the middle of another.

To do RCA, I tried logging all payloads to the celery task logger. Even in the logger, a log would start in the middle of another.

Could all this be because multiple celery workers are writing to the same file? How can I avoid this ... I'm okay with each worker writing to a different file.

Comment: Did you use Celery's `get_task_logger` ?

Comment: Yes, i used get_task_logger